# MySQL / Classic ASP - Record Count

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I'm trying to add a count of all returned records in to my query, but having some issues. It's a very large query so I won't post it all.

When this executes, I get all records but the count rs.Fields("totalRecCount") always returns with 1. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong and suggest a fix?

This is the top part:

```
Set cmdConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmdConn.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmdConn.Prepared = True

Const ad_varChar = 200
Const ad_ParamInput = 1
Const ad_Integer = 3

selectClause = "SELECT COUNT(photoID) AS totalRecCount, photoID FROM photoSearch "
whereClause = "WHERE photoStatus = 'Live' "
```

This is the bottom part:

```
groupBy = "GROUP BY photoID "
orderClause = "ORDER BY dateCreated DESC "

SQL = selectClause & whereClause & groupBy & orderClause & limitClause
cmdConn.CommandText = SQL

Set rsPhotoSearch = cmdConn.Execute
```

Comment: All you/we need to know is the final SQL clause.

Comment: What's your `limitClause` doing on a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I don't know @p.campbell, that's why I'm getting help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns 1 because you're grouping by the very thing you want to count. Remove your `group by` clause and the `photoId` column, and you'll get your record count.

The `group by` is telling MySQL, "For each distinct `PhotoID`, count the number of non-null `PhotoID`s." By definition, that's 1.

Comment: I need to select the photoID column

Comment: @MartinG - Then select it. MySQL allows you to select columns that aren't contained the `group by` clause, even though aggregate functions are used. It's the only RDBMS that I've spent any time with that does this. At any rate, realize what that recordset will give you: The same record count along with each `photoID`. So if you have 87 records, each row will be `87, photoID`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
selectClause = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRecCount, photoID FROM photoSearch "
whereClause = "WHERE photoStatus = 'Live' "   
groupBy = "GROUP BY photoID "
SQL = selectClause & whereClause & groupBy
cmdConn.CommandText = SQL
```